# discord.js remove a user from channel permissions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was wondering if anyone out there knows if there is a way to remove a user from the list of allowed users/roles in textchannel permissions.  I know that I can simply deny a READ_MESSAGES permission for that user in the channel to make the room invisible to them.  Is there a way to have my bot remove the allowed user from the permission list all-together?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by that: are you trying to delete a permission overwrite (like when you click "Remove" at the end of the permission page in your Discord app)?

Comment: Yes.  Right now I have only been able to change a user's permission to a channel to not being able to read in order to remove them from access to that channel.  I'm trying to have them removed from the permissions list of the channel all-together.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As of writing this answer (March 30, 2021) and Discord.js version 12.5.1 the answer is:

```
// type is either 'member' or 'role'
// id is either the user or role id

const id = "12345678910112"
const type = "member"

await channel.permissionOverwrites.find(o => o.type === type && o.id === id).delete()
```

If you want to delete multiple users/roles:

```
const type = 'member'
const ids = ['123456789012323', '1234567890123455']

await Promise.all(channel.permissionOverwrites.filter(o => o.type === type && ids.includes(o.id)).map(o => o.delete()));
```

If you want to delete every user/role:

```
const type = 'member'

await Promise.all(channel.permissionOverwrites.filter(o => o.type === type).map(o => o.delete()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`replacePermissionOverwrites`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=replacePermissionOverwrites):

```
channel.replacePermissionOverwrites({
  "overwrites": channel.permissionOverwrites.filter(o => o.id !== idOfUserToRemove)
});
```

Comment: I shall give this a shot.  Thank you.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try.  Unfortunately it comes back with an error.

/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Permissions.js:194
11:21 PM
    if (typeof permission !== 'number' || permission < 0) throw new RangeError(Constants.Errors.NOT_A_PERMISSION);
11:21 PM
                                                          ^
11:21 PM

11:21 PM
RangeError: Invalid permission string or number.

Comment: Apparently it was so simple, I completely missed it.


It is just




channel.permissionOverwrites.get(UserID or RoleID).delete();



Thanks for your help!